# using mac book pro (mid 2010) as monitor for a DVR

Tags: macbook-pro, display, vga

I recently bought a DVR and set of security cameras. The DVR has a VGA port and an HDMI port. I connected my MBP to the DVR VGA port using a Mini Display port adapter. However, I do not see the DVR display on my MBP. I'm assuming that I cannot use my MBP to view the DVR. Is that right? Or do I have to buy a monitor separately to view the DVR? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd just be better off buying another monitor, as that is Mini-DVI *out* not in. I'm sure that there are ways around this, but buying a separate monitor would be way easier.